# Real head modeling enliven grandfather

Tags: modeling

Hello is there any good tutorial for real head modeling in blender 2.8 i would like to model and enliven my grandfather from old photography. Thank you very much

Comment: https://cvl-demos.cs.nott.ac.uk/vrn/index.php

Comment: Next time please use the blender artists forum for this kind of questions. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86JiuZpbi_w